# C elf.h get offset of ELF64_Shdr

Tags: c, hex, elf

I am working with elf.h in C and I have an `ELF64_Shdr *sh` that I need to get the offset for. I'm getting it like this:

```
unsigned char offset = sh->sh_offset;
printf("Offset: %x\n",offset);
```

but this prints "Offset: c0" when I know the value to actually be 6c0 (garnered from the elf command line tool). Strangely, if I do this:

```
printf("Offset: %x\n",sh->sh_offset);
```

it prints "Offset: 5c0", which is closer but still not quite right. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `6c0` doesn't fit in a char.

Comment: Dang, I feel foolish. Thanks! Still don't know how to get the right offset though.

Comment: `sh->sh_offset` is of type uint64_t but `%x` to `printf` expects an `int` (usually 32 bits). You can try to use `%lx` to `printf` since you are passing an long int. I'm not sure if that will fix the problem, tough.

Comment: Just tried this, and returns the same. I also tried `printf("Offset: %d\n", sh->sh_offset)` and got 1472, which is also 5c0.

Answer (score 0):

> `unsigned char offset = sh->sh_offset;`

That is your problem *right there*. You are truncating a 64-bit entity of type `Elf64_Off` to 8-bits. Don't do *that*!

If you need to save the offset, then save it in a variable of appropriate type:

```
Elf64_Off offset = sh->sh_offset;
```

To print it, use `%lx` format specifier.